# Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]

Tags: php, pear, require-once

When i try to call require_once function that gave to me following error message [image]

I'm sure "/www/mvc/controllers/router.php" is correct path for my router.php file

Comment: please type out the error message. I can't read the image, it's too small.

Comment: @Paul Made it clickable for you. :)

Comment: The file calling require_once is not in the right location to reference the ur url

Comment: what's that nicely error report with call stack?

Comment: Is folder "www" your document root? Then try "/mvc/controllers/router.php"

Comment: @yes [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/).

Comment: @yes123 - xdebug enabled gives that nice stack trace

Comment: Oh nice, well i made my custom error handler that pretty much does that

Answer (score 3):

Paths starting with `/` are *absolute to the system root*. Meaning `/var/www/foo/bar` would be something like `C:\var\www\foo\bar` on Windows, which, looking at your debug message, is quite obviously not where your files are. Leave off the starting `/` to make the path *relative to the current script*, or fix your path.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you don't have `/www/mvc/controllers/router.php` on Windows. And you're on windows, as indicated by include path `C:\php\pear` and script path `C:\wamp\www\mvc\index.php`